# UIImageView rotation on touching a scrollview - iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have seen examples of rotating a `UIImageView` on touch. I have a case where I'm supposed to rotate the `UIImageView` on scrolling the `UIScrollView`. The UIImageView is the content of `UIScrollView`. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the delegate to scroll view and call this method:

```
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
```

Inside of that rotate the imageview:

```
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633); //90 degrees
```

then set it back when

```
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.57079633); //90 degrees
```

Comment: The imageview is a wheel. So is it possible to keep rotating until the scrollView decelerates?

Comment: What kind of wheel? Like a prize wheel or just a spinning icon?

Comment: Either way, this answer should work from what your question says. If you've seen the examples for rotating on touch. Just use scrollViewWillBeginDragging to call [self startSpinning:imgView]; and didEndDecelerating to call [self stopSpinning:imgView];

Comment: the wheel is a car tyre rotation. just a normal rotation. not like the wheel of fortune

Comment: I haven't tested this but it seems like others like this way of spinning a uiview: http://stackoverflow.com/a/518620/879119