# Animating a "character" within iOS app that's not SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in talks with a client to do an app, but in it, they are wanting it to revolve around a little character that follows you throughout the app (think Clippy, from the old days of Microsoft Word :)).

One thought I had was, can I use an `SKSprite/Node` inside an iOS app *not* using the SpriteKit framework?

Or is this a matter of animating through an array of `UIImages`?

Those were my first thoughts - does anyone know the best direction to go in for something like this? I need basic animations for a character throughout the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the detail of animation needed, you could do it with just CoreAnimation and possibly selectively choosing the image to display in an UIImageView.  For example, see the answers to this question: [rotate a UIView around its center but several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518530/rotate-a-uiview-around-its-center-but-several-times/9491508#9491508)

Comment: Ended up doing something like this. I actually wrote an API for character animations inside a normal run of the mill iOS project and will share it if it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, No, out of the box you can't use a class from a framework and choose to not use the framework. Though I'm not exactly sure what that question means. An SKSpriteNode renders via an SKScene node, and an SKScene node renders via an SKView, which is rendered by a View Controller.

You could do something fancy like dedicate the SKView as only part of the screen, and have a standard UIKit view as the other part, or only have the SKView appear on the screen when you needed it I guess.