# Can I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate a view more than 360 degrees?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm writing an iPhone app, and I've got an image which I'ld like to have swirl outwards.

Currently my code looks like this (wrapped in a beginAnimations/commitAnimations block):

```
scale = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 5.0f, 5.0f);
swirl = CGAffineTransformRotate(scale, M_PI);
[player setTransform:swirl];    
[player setAlpha:0.0f];
```

But I find that if I try to change the angle of the rotation to, say, 4*M_PI, it doesn't rotate at all.  Is it possible to get a 720˚ rotation using CGAffineTransformRotate, or do I have to switch to another technology?

If I have to switch to another technology, would you recommend using another thread (or a timer) to do the animation myself, or would OpenGL be a better route to go?

Thanks,
Blake.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can rotate a view, by some number of radians, regardless of whether it is less than a full rotation or many multiples of a full rotation, without having to split the rotation into pieces.  As an example, the following code will spin a view, once per second, for a specified number of seconds.  You can easily modify it to spin a view by a certain number of rotations, or by some number of radians.

```
- (void) runSpinAnimationWithDuration:(CGFloat) duration;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [myView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for posting it and for insisting when commenting on other people's posts! I was about to split my animation!

Comment: make sure you do this for transform.rotation.z I had issues trying to just do it on transform with CATransform3DMakeRotation.  I kept running into "gimbal lock" when I used the make rotation function.  When I use transform.rotation.z as stated above it works beautifully!

Comment: This was great. But it seemed that "rotations" turned out to be "rotations / second". Still very useful. I guess the simplest way to rotate it on the other axes is to add separate animations, just change the keypath?

Answer (score 5):

You can, but you will need to split your animation into half-circle rotations.  I provide an example of this in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486609/how-can-i-use-animation-in-cocos2d/493680#493680), using a repeating CABasicAnimation applied to the layer underneath the view.  As I suggest there, doing these half-rotations as parts of a CAKeyframeAnimation would probably be the better way to structure this, because the animation would be smoother (there's a slight hitch in between half-rotations in my example), and you could do a nice acceleration / deceleration at the start and end.

Comment: Cool.  This seems to do what I was hoping for, and I figure I can add a scaling transform to it as well, and get a notification back to my class on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: It is incorrect to say that you have to split an animation into half-circle rotations.  See my answer.

Comment: You do, if you rely on a CATransform3D as the value you're animating.  I hadn't thought about your approach, using the keypath extensions that Core Animation provides for the transform structure fields.  You're right, that's probably a cleaner way to approach this.

Answer (score 5):

Answer to title: Yes, CGAffineTransform can rotate more than 360 degrees just fine.
Answer to question: Yes, but you cannot animate it because there is nothing to animate.

Remember that [the affine transformation is a matrix](http://tinyurl.com/bp2e8x), and that a rotation matrix contains the sine and cosine numbers *precomputed*. It's as if you said:

```
CGFloat angle = 4.0 * M_PI;
NSAffineTransformStruct matrix = {
    .m11 = cos(angle),
    .m12 = sin(angle),
    .m21 = -sin(angle),
    .m22 = cos(angle),
    .tx = 0.0,
    .ty = 0.0
};
NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[transform setTransformStruct:matrix];
```

Now, let's review some sample values for `cos` and `sin`:

- `cos(0π)` = 1
- `sin(0π)` = 0
- `cos(2π)` = 1
- `sin(2π)` = 0
- `cos(4π)` = 1
- `sin(4π)` = 0

Remember, **the matrix doesn't contain the angle -- it only contains the cosine and sine**. And those values don't change from one multiple of a circle to another. Therefore, there is nothing to animate.

(Note that Calculator.app gives wrong results for cos(xπ) and sin(xπ). Try Grapher, [calc](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/), or [Google](http://tinyurl.com/aztfkw).)

You will need to split the animation into fractions of a circle. The half-circles Brad Larson suggested will do just fine.

Comment: You don't have to split the animation.  See my answer.