# How to rotate an image using touch

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me that how can i rotate a view with respect to touch given by user....

I mean  i want to make similar appearance like the old telephones were(press and rotate to dial...)...[image]

I know very well how to rotate but was unable to rotate according to this situation.....

Comment: I just wrote a long answer about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119743/how-to-rotate-image-around-center-point-automatically-with-finger-touch/6910074#6910074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a view with only the dial image.

```
This view has a center C(x,y)
First, the view will be touched at coordinate T0(x,y)

if the x and y is within the circle do the tracking:
    Then the finger will move to coordinate Tn(x,y) 
    Find the angle made up by Tn(x,y) C(x,y) T0(x,y)  //(See below for a reference)
    and do the rotation using that angle as you already know ;)
else
   do nothing since the touch is not in the dial
```

Ref: [How to calculate an angle from three  points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points)

Answer (score 3):

Calculate angle between the starting touch and the center of the dial (`atan2f(y - yc, x - xc)`), and use that as the basis angle to determine the rotation required for each subsequent touch event.