# Moving Image 360 Degree

Tags: iphone

How can we Move an Image 360 Degree from the starting point to the ending point?
Moving Image 360 Degree?

Comment: not to sound rude , but do you mean 360 degree's rotation ? Wouldnt that just the image back in the same orientation ? or do you mean translation ?

Comment: As mahboudz points out, your question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542739/can-i-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-to-rotate-a-view-more-than-360-degrees

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a view, by some number of radians, regardless of whether it is less than a full rotation or many multiples of a full rotation, without having to split the rotation into pieces.  As an example, the following code will spin a view, once per second, for a specified number of seconds.  You can easily modify it to spin a view by a certain number of rotations, or by some number of radians.

```
- (void) runSpinAnimationWithDuration:(CGFloat) duration;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [myView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 360 degree rotation in any axis leaves the view unchanged. So don't touch the image, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an animation function (CAValueFunction) for this too:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2.0];
rotationAnimation.valueFunction = [CAValueFunction functionWithName:kCAValueFunctionRotateZ];
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

[myView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:nil];
```