# Spinning Wheel Game: Trouble with rotation image

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate a view more than 360 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542739/can-i-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-to-rotate-a-view-more-than-360-degrees)

I'm trying to create a game where pushing a button spins an dial image, having trouble with the rotation code. Goal is to spin the image from its current position by a % of 360, i.e .4 * 360, spin the image 144 degrees. Thanks Guys!

```
-(IBAction)spin:(id)sender
{

    float strenght = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(.5 * 360);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^
    {
        [spinner_iv setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([spinner_iv transform],strenght)];
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        //done
    }];
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? What is/isn't working?

Comment: just gives unexpected results, it works if rotating by <179 degrees at a time, anything over doesn't work. Noticed when NSLogging my spinner_iv rotation it goes from 0-180,-180-0... i'm lost. oh and thank you for responding.

Comment: Show your `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS` code

Comment: proj -> http://cl.ly/EOu6 , it's literally 4 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

UIView animations using `CGAffineTransform` take the 'shortest path', so if you request a clockwise rotation of 270 degrees, it will animate anticlockwise by 90 degrees.

You can get any number of spins if you instead rotate the **view layer** using `CATransform3D` - yes, use this even if you are rotating in 2D.  See [Can I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate a view more than 360 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542739/1318452)

Answer (score 0):

Converting degrees to radians is

Radians = Degrees * (PI/180)

Comment: I couldn't see your code, so I'm guessing this might be what's wrong.