# How to create a rotating circle?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, geometry

I'm trying to make a simple "rotating gear animation." Basically, I want to put a circle on the screen at a certain position, and give this circle an image of gear (or just make the image rotating without creating a circle at first). Also, the gear should keep rotating. How can I achieve that?

I'm beginner to ios development. If anyone can provide a simple sample code, I will really appreciate that!

Comment: You forgot to post the code you currently have.

Comment: https://github.com/jonasschnelli/UIView-i7Rotate360

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually rotate a `UIImageView` infinitely.

Firstly `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
  - (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration rotations:    (CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Assume that you have a `UIImageView` and assign an image on it and named ImgView. On `viewDidLoad`, add your code as below:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:MAXFLOAT];
ImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

From the links :-

[UIView Infinite 360 degree rotation animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844925/uiview-infinite-360-degree-rotation-animation)

[Infinite rotating image background UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715967/infinite-rotating-image-background-uiimageview)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use block-based animations as the Apple recommends for iOS4+? now, we are almost iOS7...