# Is C++ and Linear Algebra a must when trying to learn and understand core graphics?

Tags: c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Currently learning IOS App development using a the big nerd ios programming book and I was on a chapter of the book that focuses heavily on CoreGraphics. I found it hard to grasp so I went through the chapter multiple times and it became slightly easier but I still wasn't 100% confident with it so decided to find a nice core graphics tutorial.

I found myself doing the ray wenderlich core graphics tutorial, it's quite good but I still noticed there where somethings I didn't quite get. Often found myself asking questions like "*why did I just do that?*", "*how am I suppose to know what floating point number to put there?*".

Anyway I woke up at 5am and have been reading various posts and webites for the last 2 and half hours. I stumbled across a [post](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=218&t=4881) that stated:

- The basics of graphics programming is necessary
- C++ is a must
- Linear Algebra is a must
- Firm knowledge of coordinate system transformation is a must

**How true is the above?**

I mean I remember in the past when learning ruby/rails I ended up needing to pick up various other things in order to be able to build complete websites. On my journey to learn IOS App development I'm starting to see the same thing happen.

I've stopped at chapter 6 of this big nerd book to focus on core graphics and now I'm not even half way through the core graphics tutorial I'm following and may need to stop and do a tutorial on linear algebra amongst other things.

I'd like to do what's really necessary. Stackoverflow is my go to place in these types of situations. I'd like to know from some of the experienced IOS App developers, what do you recommend in this situation?

**Is there a set guide you recommend I follow?**

I promised myself I was going to learn IOS Dev properly with no short cuts as understand things thoroughly has made the experience quite enjoyable.

I came across a linear algebra video course on khanacademy. But I'd really only like to put time into what's necessary. I work full time, currently trying to make the transition from networking into the web development industry so I can naturally put time into it rather than having to sacrifice evenings and weekends.

My aim is to be able to build a fully fledged app. E.g. Like twitter, facebook, tagged. I won't be doing any fancy graphics just the kind you'd see on the sites I mentioned.

Your advice will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: CoreGraphics is a C API, I'm not sure why you would need C++ for it. Geometry is certainly important and linear algebra can't hurt, but whether they are a _must_ depend on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: My aim is to be able to build a fully fledged app. E.g. Like twitter, facebook, tagged. I won't be doing any fancy graphics just the kind you'd see on the sites I mentioned. I'd like to be able to take care of the look and feel of the app myself.

Comment: The aforementioned application don't even use Core Graphics? Though if you want to make a 3D (maybe with OpenGL), a FIRM understanding of the coordinate system (3D) is a must. Ex: when you need to create lighting for an object, you can't stand there, calculating for an hour the coordinates the light should come from.

Comment: Chances are these apps use very little CoreGraphics. Most of their custom visuals will be done offline in Photoshop, with animations and basic effects (e.g. shadows, borders, etc.) handled by CoreAnimation.

Comment: You don't need C++ or much of an understanding of linear algebra to do that kind of very basic graphics. Focus on the "somethings I didn't quite get" (what are they?) and not what some bozo on some message board suggested that Everyone Absolutely Must Learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The basics of graphics programming is necessary

Technically true, but Core Graphics is a great way to *learn* (at least 2D) graphics programming.

> - C++ is a must

False.

> - Linear Algebra is a must

It's involved, but you can ignore the man behind the curtain 90+% of the time.

The only time I can remember the matrix nature of affine transformations becoming important was [the time I answered a question about infinite rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543608/30461)—and even then, [another answerer provided a solution that didn't rely on matrix knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423495/30461).

[Apple's own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1) says:

“You can use either set of functions [making matrixes directly from numbers vs. geometric transformations] without understanding anything about matrix math. However if you want to understand what Quartz does when you call one of the transform functions, read [‘The Math Behind the Matrices.’](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD)”

I would only add that if you do read “The Math Behind the Matrices” and it's lost on you, don't worry about it—just try it again in a month. At some point, you'll read that chapter and it'll make sense.

Geometry and trigonometry are much more important as a Core Graphics user than linear algebra. And [the trig you need to know is pretty straightforward](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2013-06-10/how-trigonometry-works).

> - Firm knowledge of coordinate system transformation is a must

Again, true, but Core Graphics is a great way to learn it.

> Is there a set guide you recommend I follow?

[The Core Graphics Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/)

If any part of it stumps you, open Xcode and start doing it. Pound on it 'til it works. Make sliders to adjust parameters (e.g., any of scale, translate, rotation angle, and skew) and fields to display them and see how the input affects the output. Experiment with blend modes.

*Definitely* experiment with blend modes.

And if you ever get completely stuck, you can always come back to SO and ask a question about it.

Comment: Very helpful, I shall make use of the information provided. The core graphics programming guide looks very helpful. I figured I might as well finish learning it all since I've started already even if I may not use it that much.