# iphone UIImageView rotation

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Can anyone tell me how to rotate an image in circular motion

Answer (score 28):

You can rotate a view, by some number of radians, regardless of whether it is less than a full rotation or many multiples of a full rotation, without having to split the rotation into pieces.  As an example, the following code will spin a view, once per second, for a specified number of seconds.  You can easily modify it to spin a view by a certain number of rotations, or by some number of radians.

```
- (void) runSpinAnimationWithDuration:(CGFloat) duration;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [myView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: i'm getting an error, " rotations undeclared"

Comment: rotations is a const.  Replace it with the number of times you want the view to rotate in duration amount of time.

Comment: I'm I'm not the

Answer (score 3):

based on mahboudz's answer, you can set it to infinitely spin by setting: 
`rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, "How do you make an image follow a circular path?", then the pseudocode would be:

```
image.x = circleCentre.x + cos(angle) * circleRadius;
image.y = circleCentre.y + sin(angle) * circleRadius;
angle += 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542739/can-i-use-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-to-rotate-a-view-more-than-360-degrees) asks the same thing, although in different words.  The answers in that question, as well as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486609/how-can-i-use-animation-in-cocos2d) should provide a way to animate a UIView (UIImageView is simply a subclass of this) about its center for 360 degrees or more.

Comment: Probably u r confused about rotation and revolution. The above question is about revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the animation

```
- (CABasicAnimation *)spinAnimationWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration clockwise:(BOOL)clockwise repeat:(BOOL)repeats
{
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    anim.toValue = clockwise ? @(M_PI * 2.0) : @(M_PI * -2.0);
    anim.duration = duration;
    anim.cumulative = YES;
    anim.repeatCount = repeats ? CGFLOAT_MAX : 0;
    return anim;
}
```

Add it to a view

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [self spinAnimationWithDuration:1.0 clockwise:YES repeat:YES];
[self.spinningView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

How is this answer different from @mahboudz's answer? You will have way cleaner code if most of your functions returns objects instead of just manipulating some objects here and there.