# How do you rotate a UIView in an animation?

Tags: iphone

I can animate a UIView with sizes and positions etc. But how do you rotate it?

Comment: This is very close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421050/iphone-uiimageview-rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change its transform matrix...here is a link to the transform property of views [transforms](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform)

You can use CGAFfineTransforms to set this property, you can either make a new one, or use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation   that takes a degree as input, here is a reference to that [CGAffineTransforms](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation)

hope that helps