# iPhone app spinning an image from the last position

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, cabasicanimation

I am trying to create an animated spinning image. This is all fine and I am using CABasicAnimation as described in this thread [how can I use animation in cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486609/how-can-i-use-animation-in-cocos2d)

My problem is that I want to spin the image more than once a random number of times and I want to spin it from it's last position. At the moment I can get the image to spin, it finishes in a random position but then if I try to add another spin it resets the image to its initial position. I have been searching for a solution for ages now, if anyone has any tips that would be most appreciated.

I guess I want to replicate the picker spinning but with a 2d image spinning around a central point - if that is clearer!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you set

```
animation.cumulative = YES;
```

?

That SHOULD have the animation continue from where the previous one left off.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that doesn't work. That just means that you can effectively loop the animation. Once that block has stopped and you re-apply it it doesn't work, it jumps back! Any other ideas?